# Clarification needed on why Client application should need both idtoken and access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Client application fetches the idtoken for authentication. But for the resource server, it needs to again make a call to Auth server and fetch the access token. Hence, does it make sense to make two calls for every oauth2.0 flow. The access token is what will be sent to the resource server. Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenID Connect, the **ID-token** is returned to the client at the same time as the **access-token**. So there is no specific need to make two requests to get the two tokens.

If you ask for an refresh token as well, then that one will also be returned at the same time.

The API (Resource Server) only receives access tokens from the client and it can without asking the identity provider validate the token. The API does not receive any ID-token.